# session_start() not working when required at top of every page

Tags: php, session

I am working on this project using login and registration forms. I have added my session_start(); variable at the top of my header.php file and requiring it to my webpages. However, the variable is giving me a session_start() warning stating the header has already been sent, but my scripts work perfectly. This is the header code for my site:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
    $url = "http://www.mydomain.com/";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> ...
```

And this is the top of my webpages:

```
<?php require ("./inc/header.php") ?>
<?php $title = "Title for webpage inserted Here"; ?>
```

I don't understand why I am getting a session_start() warning. Please help!

Comment: There is probably some whitespace before the `<?php` opening tag.

Comment: Try to remove `session_start();` if your session is working I think you dont need to place `session_start()` again. Maybe your page is controlled by other page function.. I got this problem too in opencart

Comment: this happens when you have stuff before the php, on line 1 you must have `<?php` and **nothing** else before

Comment: I have tried removing the session_start(); which does remove the error, but my script wont log a user in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem. Koen was correct with the whitespace... I just eliminated the whitespace, required the session_start(); variable to each page and ftp the file to my server and it fixed the problem. Thanks for the ideas and the suggestions. Much appreciated the help!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your configuration is set to use cookies only, add this at the top: ini_set("session.use_only_cookies", "0");

Comment: Try: ini_set("session.use_only_cookies",0);

Comment: And: ini_set("session.use_trans_sid",1);